# Are parameters for geometeric brownian motion updated for all data points that are in the dataset?

Tags: forecasting, brownian-motion

Assuming I have a time-varying stochastic data-set (i.e Prices for stock etc. ) and I want to forecast the price of the stock at any time step into the future, let's say 1 day into the future.

Now for the said task, I want to use Geometric Brownian motion to model the stochastic phenomena. Now to completely define the GBM model, we need to estimate drift parameter and volatility parameter, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ respectively.

A GBM model is defined in the following manner([Source](https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/810fa2af-78a4-45f3-828e-6391842c5f26/content)):

[image]

Or alternatively as (just different notation from [Source](https://d-nb.info/1211448533/34)):

[image]

[image]

Following are the ways we can estimate the said parameters([Source](https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/810fa2af-78a4-45f3-828e-6391842c5f26/content)):

[image]

Now once the parameters are estimated for any set of time-varying stochastic data points in the entire data-set, in our case say stock prices.

My questions are the following:

Q) For forecasting one day ahead (if $t$ is present, we want stock prices for $t+1$), do we freeze the parameters that we estimated earlier while attempting to get forecast into the future? This in sense, would be like how we train neural networks and how we vary parameter $\alpha$ to get desired output, and once we find such an $\alpha$ we freeze it for the prediction\testing phase.

Q) Given the idea of training\estimating of said parameters of GBM is similar to that of neural network's $\alpha$, would I be correct to assume that we need to split the data-set in (let's say 70-30 split) for training \ estimating parameters and leave out the rest for forecasting\testing?

My main understanding of prediction\forecasting comes from neural networks, so please point me in the right direction if my understanding of how the GBM model works is flawed.